# Override media queries in CSS files with custom CSS in HTML

Tags: html, css, adminlte

I am using an HTML template (Admin LTE) for my angular project. In it I tried to override a default width specification using this in my index.html head section

```
  @media(min-width: 768px)
  {
    body:not(.sidebar-mini-md):not(.sidebar-mini-xs):not(.layout-top-nav) .content-wrapper, body:not(.sidebar-mini-md):not(.sidebar-mini-xs):not(.layout-top-nav) .main-footer, body:not(.sidebar-mini-md):not(.sidebar-mini-xs):not(.layout-top-nav) .main-header
    {
      margin: left 300px!important;
    }
  }
```

But when executing, its not at all taking my custom css in index.html, instead it takes the 250px which is hardcoded in the CSS file

[image]

SO How to override this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is not valid as shown in dev tools:

```
margin: left 300px !important
```

Try:

```
margin-left: 300px !important
```

Comment: Oh mann.. I should not miss that typo.. Realy sorry..